# jaxb entity print out as xml

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a class, let's call it **User** annotated with `@XmlRootElement`, with some properties (name, surname etc).

I use this class for REST operations, as `application/xml`.

The client will POST User class so i want to keep the values in the log.

Is there any method in jaxb to prints out this object **as xml**?

For instance:

```
log.info("Customers sent: "+user.whichMethod());
```

should produce this output:

```
Customer sent:
```

```
<user> <name>cristi</name> <surname>kevin</surname> </user>
```

Thanks.

Comment: That has nothing to do with JAX-WS, you only need JAXB (the tags are correct, but you mention JAX-WS in the text).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found:)

```
public void toXml() {
    try {
        JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(User.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = ctx.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(this, System.out);
    }
    catch (Exception
            e) {

              //catch exception 
    }
}
```

Call it like:

```
log.info("Customers sent: "+user.toXml());
```

Comment: **Never** write an empty catch-block, not even in an example! Examples have the nasty habit of turning into production code at some point and we need to maintain that mess, then.

Answer (score 21):

You can make this as a common method accessible by your endpoints.

```
public String toXml(JAXBElement element) {
    try {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(element.getValue().getClass());  
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();  
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);  

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        marshaller.marshal(element, baos);
        return baos.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }      
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting `Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT` may be not good for logging.

Instead suppress `XML Prolog (or Declaration)` with `Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT`.

```java
public static <J> String printXml(final J instance) throws JAXBException {
    return printXml(instance, instance.getClass());
}


public static <J> String printXml(final J instance,
                                  final Class<?>... classesToBeBound)
    throws JAXBException {

    final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(classesToBeBound);

    final ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    final Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);
    marshaller.marshal(instance, output);
    // output.flush(); // Nasty IOException
    final String jaxbEncoding = (String) marshaller.getProperty(
        Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING);

    try {
        return new String(output.toByteArray(), jaxbEncoding);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
        throw new RuntimeException(uee);
    }
}
```

will prints a single line like this.

```xml
<user><name>cristi</name><surname>kevin</surname></user>
```

Comment: Since such a method likely is used for log outputs I would not throw, instead catch all Exception, log it (either to a logger or to the console) and return ""+instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String toXml(Event event) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos =  null;

    try {

         JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(event.getClass());  
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();  
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);  

        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        marshaller.marshal(event, baos);
        return baos.toString();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, " problem in  Logging raw XML  :"+e.getMessage());
    }      
    return baos.toString();
```

This Works well